# NPOI C# copy sheet with image

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I try make copy of XSSF sheet with images in one workbook like this:

```
ISheet newSheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0).CopySheet(value.ToString());
workbook.Add(newSheet);
```

Everyhing except images is copied correctly. When I open document with copied sheets the images are corrupted and are not displayed.
The sheet is in xlsx format.

NPOI version is 2.1.3 for .NET 2.0. The project is written in .NET 3.5

Do you know how to copy entire sheet with images?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in NPOI version 2.1.3. It has bug. **Update to 2.1.3.1** had helped.